# Rails: When adding column :username to devise, username value still shows as nil in console when I create a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm stuck on an issue.

I wanted to add a username field to my users table in the devise gem. I first ran the rails migration..

```
$ rails g migration AddUsernameToUsers
```

After updating with rake db:migrate, I added a column and index to the AddUsernameToUsers migration file like so..

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]`

  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string
    add_index :users, :username, unique: true
  end
end
```

I then rendered the new username field in the new.html.erb view in the devise folder with

`<%= f.input :username, required:true %>`

[screenshot of the new.html.erb devise view file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xevdw.png)

I restarted the rails server (if that helps at all) and then the username field showed up correctly in the view, allowed me to add a username and create an account successfully, however when I check the rails console the username value still showed as `username: nil`, like this...

[rails console example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT73o.png)

```
2.4.0 :002 > @u = User.last
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 4, email: "hello@gmail.com", created_at: "2017-09-07 09:10:31", updated_at: "2017-09-07 09:10:31", username: nil>
```

can somebody please tell me what I'm missing? How can I make sure that the input value saves to the username field instead of giving `:nil`.

For reference, my User model looks like this..

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

and my Application Controller looks like this...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

end
```

I hope i was clear enough, help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Ant

Comment: Are you using rails spring?

Comment: Is `username` an **un-permitted attribute** in the `UsersController`? In this case, the column will not be updated.

Comment: I would also suggest adding a validation to the `User` model, to ensure the field is present. This should highlight the issue, as you'll be unable to save the record.

Comment: Yes i see gem 'spring' is in the development group in my gemfile

Comment: @TomLord how would I permit the username attribute?

Comment: @AntChamberlin in the `UsersController`. Along with the other attributes that are already being permitted. If you edit your post to include the `UsersController` code, I can see if that's the issue, and show the fix.

Comment: @TomLord have edited my post, hopefully ive included the right things.. i dont have a UsersController with devise

Comment: OK, so you're using Devise's built-in `RegistrationsController`. [Read this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) section of the Devise README; I believe that answers your question.

Comment: @TomLord Perfecto! That seems to be the fix, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form submission is being sent to the `Devise::RegistrationsController`, which - by default, will only **permit** the following parameters: `:email`, `:password` and `:password_confirmation`. If you view the rails log while submitting this form, you should see an error like:

> unpermitted attribute: :username

There are a few possible solutions outlined in the [Devise README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters); the simplest solution in your case being:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

You can read more about strong parameters [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) in the rails docs.

On a separate note, I would suggest adding the following validation rule to your model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, presence: true
end
```

You could also consider doing something like "if no username is supplied, set it to equal the email address".

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly! I added the code and can now see in rails console that username is populated with the input. Another question, what is the purpose/benefit of the validates rule, if the first solution worked fine?

Comment: As I say, the validation is a separate suggestion. But for example, your current code will (bizarrely) allow **one** (and only one) user to be created with no username!

Comment: You may also choose to make that validation rule a bit stricter - e.g. "username must be at least 6 characters"

Comment: ......Or maybe you'd rather remove the *database constraint* to have a unique username, and instead say "only validate that the username is unique, if it is present".

Comment: Right, I see. So if I wanted to implement stricter validation rules, would I do this through if/else statements inside the Application controller?

Comment: Validation should typically be done in the model. You can read about them here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html